# Проблема с установкой Monodevelop-5

Tags: linux-mint, linux

Пытаюсь установить Monodevelop-5 на Linux Cinnamon [отсюда](URL)

Мои действия:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ermshiperete/monodevelop
2. sudo apt-get update

Ответ на первый пункт:

---

```
MonoDevelop as well as Mono 3.x will be installed in /opt/monodevelop.

There is a monodevelop-launcher.sh script in /opt/monodevelop/bin that can be used to start MonoDevelop.

Install package monodevelop-current to always get the latest release.
 Больше информации: https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/ubuntu/monodevelop
Нажмите [ENTER] для продолжения или Ctrl-C для отмены добавления

gpg: запрашиваю ключ 839ECBBE с hkp сервера keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: ключ 839ECBBE: "Launchpad PPA for Eberhard Beilharz" не изменен
gpg: Всего обработано: 1
gpg:              неизмененных: 1
```

---

Апдейт проходит без проблем, но папки /opt/monodevelop нет.

Подскажите, как установить программу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/~inizan-yannick/+archive/ubuntu/mono - исправил, установив из этого репозитория.

Answer (score 1):

Ты всего лишь установил репозиторий и обновил списки пакетов. Надо командой sudo apt-get install monodevelop-5 установить MonoDevelop.